# How to use Stream for inner for loops

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have an Order object which consist of List of Order Entry instances which in turn consist of List of Tax  instances.

Order contains List of OrderEntry,

OrderEntry contains List of Tax and,

Tax has method getValue which returns double.

By using Stream I want to know the best way to get sum of all the taxes in all the order entries present in a order.

Comment: stream over the list of `OrderEntry` and `flatMap` to `getValue` stream while `summingDouble`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to show us in code what you have and what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Fix for the same is below:

`double sum = orderSample.getOrderEntries().stream()
        .mapToDouble(oe -> oe.getListOfTaxes().stream().mapToDouble(Tax::getValue).sum()
        ).sum();`